# VPC can't access database instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

(Ruby 2.1.2, Rails 4). I am trying to deploy an app using Amazon EC2 for my instance, using Amazon RDS for my Postgres database. I am using dokku-alt for deployment (similar to dokku).

For some reason, I am unable to connect to my database. The log shows:

```
05:22:06 worker.1 | [Worker(host:b6c9d96b9868 pid:14)] Error while reserving job: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "medclerk5prod1"
05:22:06 worker.1 | FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "medclerk5prod1"
05:22:06 worker.1 | 2014-10-17T05:22:06+0000: [Worker(host:b6c9d96b9868 pid:14)] Error while reserving job: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "medclerk5prod1"
05:22:06 worker.1 | FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "medclerk5prod1"
05:22:06 worker.1 | 
05:22:07 web.1    | I, [2014-10-17T05:22:07.037335 #13]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:5000 fd=9
05:22:07 web.1    | E, [2014-10-17T05:22:07.059422 #13] ERROR -- : FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "medclerk5prod1"
05:22:07 web.1    | FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "medclerk5prod1"
05:22:07 web.1    |  (PG::ConnectionBad)
```

I am certain the environment variable is set for my database.yml to use (this is how the username is obtained as well). The password includes lower and upper case letters, and digits. I have checked again and again, restarted the app multiple times, tried a different password, and am stumped.

I also tried accessing the database with the correct credentials using pgAdmin3, which works fine. I also able to access the db through the terminal on my local machine.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Where are you trying to connect from? Did you check the security group settings between the worker instance and the DB?

Comment: It looks like a it is not a networking issue, but a local environment/credential issue. Can you confirm whether you can connect via command line (outside of code) ? This way we can determine whether it is an AWS/Networking misconfiguration or a code issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was an environment/credential issue. I was able to connect via the command line.

I noticed that the password, which I set using an environment variable, is different from what I had typed in originally, when using the `dokku config:set <app> <key>=<value>` command. Perhaps this is a bug with dokku-alt...?

The password should have been: `med45$$clerk76XOL55`, but it was saved as: `med4512841clerk76XOL55`

It appears as though the special symbols were altered.

After that, I rebooted the app, and it appears to connect fine to the DB.